# How to multiply months to current date upto 1 year

Tags: db2

I wanted to show the forecast dates with the current date plus frequency up to one year in DB2.

date :Current date

if frequency is :2

upto : 2020-01-01

output be like :

2019-05-22,
2019-07-22,
2019-09-22,
2019-11-22

Answer (score 2):

Try the following RCTE:

```
with t(dt) as (
values current date
  union all
select dt + 2 month
from t
where year(dt + 2 month) = year(current date)
)
select dt
from t;
```